# adjusting background layout size as text size in chatting application

Tags: android, chat

I want to adjust the background layout as the text size like in Whatsapp and other chatting applications [currently my app is looking like this :

[image]

and I want to change it like this how can I do this :

[image]

Please help me

Comment: Share your xml code

Comment: TextView msg = new TextView(Chat.this);

                        msg.setText(allMsg.getString(j));
                        msg.setTextSize(20);

                        if(allUser.getString(j).equals(pref.getString("userName", null))) {
                            msg.setWidth(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            msg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                            msg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.new3));
                            msg.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner));

Comment: i done this using java code

Comment: https://justpaste.it/14f3b that's the XML file

Comment: use padding to give proper spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your message width to `android:layout_width=wrap_content`. Share your `message xml` .

Comment: Can you share you xml design ..so that people can easily find out where you are doing wrong.

Comment: TextView msg = new TextView(Chat.this);

                        msg.setText(allMsg.getString(j));
                        msg.setTextSize(20);

                        if(allUser.getString(j).equals(pref.getString("userName", null))) {
                            msg.setWidth(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            msg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                            msg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.new3));
                            msg.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner));

Comment: and this is the part of java code I'm using for textview

Comment: <LinearLayout
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:id="@+id/msg_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"> Here You change width to wrap_content

Comment: msg.setWidth(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); msg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);  In this line of code this is taking full screen width because .. In Linear layout you have make the width for match parent ... So change there it will work for sure

Comment: If you are getting the solution dont forget to make this one as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Give proper breathing space to text using padding. And don't use static dimensions. Do like this

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="16dp"
      android:text="Your Text"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="15sp" 
      android:background="@drawable/background"/>
```